# Java RPG: Useful tools

Tags: java

I was thinking about taking on an rpg project in Java from scratch but I have never tried doing much in the way of Java games. It's not going to be very graphically intense; it is going to be 2-D and I want to use a style similar to the older, tile-based RPGs. I was wondering if there were any useful tools that anyone thinks may help.

Currently, I only have Eclipse and NetBeans; any input/suggestions are appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For developing a 2D Java game from scratch, a good 2d game engine is still needed.

I recommend **[slick](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/)**, one picture that you may be interested in[image](from its gallery)

**[JGame](http://www.13thmonkey.org/~boris/jgame/)** is also an option. It supports Eclipse: http://www.13thmonkey.org/~boris/jgame/eclipse.html

A good article for introducing JGame: 
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2006/jw-1205-games.html

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a tile-based Java roguelike/RPG many years ago using just plain vanilla Eclipse. Worked fine for me.

Full source code here if you are interested (GPL open source):

- [Tyrant - Java Roguelike](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tyrant/)

Nowadays I would probably also add the following tools:

- Maven (m2eclipse) - for handling dependencies / 3rd party libraries
- EGit / Github - for source code control
- Photoshop - for creating and touching up graphics tiles

Comment: Can't. Stop. Playing. Aha... question.. would you say character balancing was the hardest part?

Comment: Character balance is a nightmare for roguelikes :-) the problem is, as you add new features they unbalance the game... so the game is effectively permanently unbalanced unless you stop adding stuff....

Comment: Still - most of the fun in roguelikes is figuring out how to use the unbalanced parts to your advantage (or if you like to give yourself an even harder challenge). so I guess it's OK.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to be a devil's advocate and tell you about [Steve Yegge's adventures developing a Java-based RPG](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2007/12/codes-worst-enemy.html), named Wyvern (sadly now defunct). His view, as I understood it, was that Java made the code too complex to maintain; it got to half a million lines long, at one stage.

Sure, you might say your game won't get that big. But don't underestimate the power of scope creep. :-)

Nevertheless, some successful games are indeed written in Java. mikera's answer is one example, as are games like Runescape or Minecraft. But still, if your game has the potential to get big, Java probably still isn't (in my opinion, and it seems Steve Yegge's also) your best choice.

Comment: That's not the fault of Java, it't the fault of choosing the wrong design / paradigm. For example, a prototype-based object system is *far superior* to typical OOP model in an RPG context. You can do prototype-based coding in Java just fine (see my Tyrant source code above for an example).

Comment: @mikera: Surely, though, if you're going to use prototype-based OOP, you'd do better to use a language that's built that way? Rhino is an excellent JavaScript runtime for the JVM, for example. To me, prototype-based OOP goes against the grain of Java.

Comment: Yeah, though well when I started in 1997 or so there weren't many alternatives to Java :-) nowadays I'd almost certainly use Clojure, but I think Java is still a decent choice providing you use it in the right way. See e.g. http://tyrant.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tyrant/tyrant/mikera/tyrant/Potion.java?revision=1.57&view=markup - I managed to get definition of new potion objects down to 3-6 lines of Java each.